# Magento 2: How to pre Open Apply Voucher Code in Checkout page

Tags: magento2, checkout, discount, checkout-page

When checkout page is loaded it shows apply **discount code section** like this

[image]

We want that it should be **preopen** as shown in below image

[image]

How to modify core magento functionality to pre open this section when we go to checkout page.

Comment: using custom theme or custom module ??

Comment: i think using custom theme would be more better.

Comment: using your theme just copy phtml file into your theme and added "active": true

Comment: thankyou. i used your below code and it worked. i added it inside my theme

Comment: ok bro... no problem.. :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have set the Discount collapsible widget to `active true`.

You can do so by overriding the template file in your custom module.

**app/code/Vendor/Module/view/frontend/layout/checkout_cart_index.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
    <body>
        <referenceContainer name="cart.summary">
            <block class="Magento\Checkout\Block\Cart\Coupon" name="checkout.cart.coupon" as="coupon" template="Vendor_Module::cart/coupon.phtml"/>
        </referenceContainer>
    </body>
</page>
```

**app/code/Vendor/Module/view/frontend/templates/cart/coupon.phtml**

```
<?php

// @codingStandardsIgnoreFile

?>
<div class="block discount" id="block-discount" data-mage-init='{"collapsible":{"openedState": "active", "active": true, "saveState": false}}'>
    <div class="title" data-role="title">
        <strong id="block-discount-heading" role="heading" aria-level="2"><?= /* @escapeNotVerified */ __('Apply Discount Code') ?></strong>
    </div>
    <div class="content" data-role="content" aria-labelledby="block-discount-heading">
        <form id="discount-coupon-form"
              action="<?= /* @escapeNotVerified */ $block->getUrl('checkout/cart/couponPost') ?>"
              method="post"
              data-mage-init='{"discountCode":{"couponCodeSelector": "#coupon_code",
                                               "removeCouponSelector": "#remove-coupon",
                                               "applyButton": "button.action.apply",
                                               "cancelButton": "button.action.cancel"}}'>
            <div class="fieldset coupon<?= strlen($block->getCouponCode()) ? ' applied' : '' ?>">
                <input type="hidden" name="remove" id="remove-coupon" value="0" />
                <div class="field">
                    <label for="coupon_code" class="label"><span><?= /* @escapeNotVerified */ __('Enter discount code') ?></span></label>
                    <div class="control">
                        <input type="text" class="input-text" id="coupon_code" name="coupon_code" value="<?= $block->escapeHtml($block->getCouponCode()) ?>" placeholder="<?= $block->escapeHtml(__('Enter discount code')) ?>" <?php if (strlen($block->getCouponCode())): ?> disabled="disabled" <?php endif; ?> />
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="actions-toolbar">
                    <?php if (!strlen($block->getCouponCode())): ?>
                        <div class="primary">
                            <button class="action apply primary" type="button" value="<?= /* @escapeNotVerified */ __('Apply Discount') ?>">
                                <span><?= /* @escapeNotVerified */ __('Apply Discount') ?></span>
                            </button>
                        </div>
                    <?php else: ?>
                        <div class="primary">
                            <button  type="button" class="action cancel primary" value="<?= /* @escapeNotVerified */ __('Cancel Coupon') ?>"><span><?= /* @escapeNotVerified */ __('Cancel Coupon') ?></span></button>
                        </div>
                    <?php endif; ?>
                </div>
            </div>
        </form>
    </div>
</div>
```

In the coupon.phtml template file, I have changed

```
<div class="block discount" id="block-discount" data-mage-init='{"collapsible":{"openedState": "active", "saveState": false}}'>
```

to

```
<div class="block discount" id="block-discount" data-mage-init='{"collapsible":{"openedState": "active", "active": true, "saveState": false}}'>
```

I have added `"active": true` in the collapsible widget configuration.

Answer (score 0):

On page Load Dynamically require to open some particulate tab.

```
require([
    'jquery',
    'accordion'
], function ($) {
    'use strict';

    jQuery( document ).ready(function() {                      
        jQuery( "#your selector" ).accordion({
            "openedState": "active",
            "collapsible": true,
            "active": [1,4], /** Integrat Dynamic open tab  */
            "multipleCollapsible": true,
        });
    });                 
});
```